# Displaying Bar Chart (and other funky graphics)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Any suggestions on freely available libraries to display a bar chart and other "cool" graphics in Visual C++?

PS: Please don't say MFC. MFC-based libraries are fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a graphing library, Qt should work pretty nicely for drawing basic graphs, more advanced things can be done using Qwt. Plus you get the advantage of system portability.

Comment: Hmmm .. short on time ; how hard is it to get up & running?

Comment: @Jacob: I've only ever used Qt for mobile development, which was pretty simple and fairly quick (Qt Creator speeds things up a lot), but it seems pretty much the same to the desktop, so I would assume the same, considering the good examples and docs the sdk comes with.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Codejock Chart Pro](http://www.codejock.com)